# Syntax error if I include input in my definition

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting a decimal to binary number converter 
the code executes if I dont have the input line
but if i include it , i get a syntax error at the if: statment

cheers

```
def convert_to_binary(n):
n=int(input('number')
      if(n > 1):
          convert_to_binary(n//2)
      print(n % 2,end='')
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong..

Comment: Why are you indenting after the input? And you're missing a closing brace on that line as well.

Comment: thankyou, fixed that one ;) now I'm just missing an argument when i run the program. If you can't tell , im veeeeerrry new to python :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are missing indentation('    ') and a `)`.
In python you need to indents the same for all lines(add extra spaces for every scope)
And you don't need '()' for `if` statements.
Not sure why you use `end=''` so removed it.

Fixed code:

```
n = int(input('number : '))

def convert_to_binary(n):
    # (n maybe here too!) n = int(input('number : '))

    if n > 1:
        convert_to_binary(n//2)

    print(n % 2)
```

Hope this helps!